# Why do inline-blocks and blocks behave differently near a floated element?

Tags: css, css-float

I noticed that inline-blocks and blocks behave differently when they are situated near a floated element : background of blocks extends under the floated element while inline-blocks wrap it entirely.

**`div` is a block :**

```
div {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em
}

div:first-child {
  background: #27A5CC;
  float: left
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 6em;
  background: #EEEEEE
}
```

[image]

**`div` is an inline-block :**

```
div {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em
}

div:first-child {
  background: #27A5CC;
  float: left
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 6em;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  display: inline-block
}
```

[image]

Is there an explanation for it?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you understand the difference between [`block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) and [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) displays. Let us now look at how [`floats`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) work:

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line. [...] Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box
>   and down the left side of a right-floated box.
>
> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge
>   touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float.
>   If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned
>   with the top of the current line box. [...]
>
> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

Your examples explained below:

**Example 1**

The first div is floated. It is taken out of the flow and aligned with left side of the parent. The second div also starts from left side **ignoring the first div as if it did not exist**.

Result: both divs end up with their top-left corners aligned with each other.

**Example 2**

The first div is floated. It is taken out of the flow and aligned with left side of the parent. The second div is an inline block element, therefore it follows the rules that apply to content flow and line boxes. It starts rendering towards the right side of first div **just as normal text would**.

Result: the second div aligns with the right side of first div.

Comment: I should probably ask a new question, but what do you think about http://jsfiddle.net/sjx7xsay/ ? `inline-block` doesn't behave like normal inline text

Comment: The first inline-block does not have any width set; it freely expands as much as possible upto 100% width. Since the current line box is shorter than 100% (because of the float) the block flows onto the next line. This is somewhat similar to fitting a short and a very long word on a line.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/salman/sjx7xsay/1/. And please do ask another question; I would love to to see second opinion(s).

Comment: Thanx for answering! Do you want that I transform the comment into a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610693/why-dont-inline-blocks-wrap-around-floating-elements

Comment: @user3790069: I feel like this would have served better as an edit to your original question, not a new question, since they're essentially asking the same thing. The other answer was not an honest answer so I have deleted it - I'm not sure if Salman A wants to keep his answer too? If so I'll merge, otherwise you can remove your posts yourselves.