# Why don't inline-blocks wrap around floating elements?

Tags: css, css-float

Why don't inline-blocks wrap around floating elements when they are higher than this floating element?

```css
div {
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    border: 1px dotted;
    float: left;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>In metus tortor, tristique imperdiet ultrices quis, cursus in tellus. Nunc lacinia tristique purus, ut pretium justo eleifend tempor. Ut dictum ac ex ut molestie. In posuere lacus ac volutpat consectetur. Donec pharetra eu lectus a luctus. Morbi et cursus orci. Donec a scelerisque magna. Morbi a vulputate risus. Nunc volutpat est non ipsum porttitor rutrum. Aliquam eu tortor quis ligula fermentum rutrum. Aenean nibh tellus, varius sit amet posuere quis, efficitur in quam. Cras fringilla tortor sit amet nibh lacinia rhoncus. Quisque orci quam, feugiat at auctor maximus, vestibulum a velit.</p>
```

[Blocks](http://jsbin.com/tevafemibamo/1/edit) and [inline elements](http://jsbin.com/yivofetiwera/2/edit) behave as expected.

Comment: If you want it to wrap, why are you changing the default block level context?

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to understand theoretically the behaviour of floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float) says

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new **block formatting
>   context** (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') **must
>   not overlap** the margin box of **any floats** in the same block formatting
>   context as the element itself.

And a [Block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) is defined like this

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
>   **inline-blocks**, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
>   boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except
>   when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
>   block formatting contexts for their contents.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: @user3790069 Well, the spec I linked is CSS 2.1, which is superseded by CSS3 modules. There it may be defined according to the new content standards, but I though linking the CSS 2.1 spec would be better because it's simpler and still applicable because of backwards compatibility. Also note that [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#block-level) and [inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#inline-level) boxes are defined in [CSS basic box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/).